# How spread syntax in object works?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

Came across the concept of creating new object using spread syntax as below

```js
const human = { age: 20 };
const john = { ...human };
john.age = 10;
console.log(human.age); // 20
console.log(john.age); // 10
```

As shown above human object get to retain it's original value. Now have a look at below code:

```js
const human = { age: 20, cars: ["toyota", "honda"] };
const john = { ...human };
john.cars[1] = "camero";
console.log(human.cars); // ["toyota", "camero"]
console.log(john.cars); // ["toyota", "camero"]
```

Can anyone explain to me why the above scenario happened? Why human's cars object get changed? It looks to me that it's very likely for developer to make mistakes without understanding how to avoid the inconsistent behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `human` only contains a *reference* to the array which contains `["toyota", "honda"]`. When you duplicate the object using the spread operator, you also duplicate the *reference*, which means that `john` has an identical reference and therefore `john.cars` is the same array as `human.cars`.

Because of this, if you modify `john.cars`, you also modify `human.cars` because they are the same array. If you want to clone an array you can also do this using the spread operator:

```js
const human = { age: 20, cars: ["toyota", "honda"] };
const john = { ...human };
john.cars = [ ... human.cars ];
john.cars[1] = "camero";
console.log(human.cars); // ["toyota", "honda"]
console.log(john.cars); // ["toyota", "camero"]
```

You will also see this type of behaviour if you clone an object that has properties which are objects:

```js
const human = { name: { first: "John", last: "Jackson" } };
const human2 = { ... human };

human2.name.first = "Ellen";

console.log(human.name.first); // Ellen
```

That's because the spread operator only copies a *reference* to the name object, not the name object itself. Therefore, modifying one modifies the other because they are the same object. This is referred to as *shallow cloning*. If you want to avoid this confusion, you need to perform a *deep clone*.

The easiest way to do this is to convert to JSON and then convert back:

```js
const human = { name: { first: "John", last: "Jackson" } };
const human2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(human));

human2.name.first = "Ellen";

console.log(human.name.first); // John
console.log(human2.name.first); // Ellen
```

Comment: If you're saying object `human`  only contains a reference to the array `["toyota","honda"]` then may i know where is this array stays? How can I reference to it without referring to `human`?

Comment: @Isaac You can't. This is JavaScript, not C++; you can't obtain pointers to memory. If you assign `human.cars` to something else, and you haven't made another reference in a different variable, then there will be no other way to access the array and it will automatically be deleted.

Comment: You should probably say that `...` is a shallow clone in the beginning of your text. That's the main reason.